# Android View outline - using a custom Path

Tags: android

When I set View's outline as follows it works just fine:

```
view.setClipToOutline(true);
view.setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
  @Override
  public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
    outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), 16);
  }
});
```

[image]

However, using a `Path` has no effect. Replace `setRoundRect` with:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addRoundRect(
  0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), 16, 16, Path.Direction.CW);
outline.setConvexPath(path);
```

[image]

How to make the view clip to the Path provided?

Comment: You might have a look here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37064491.

Comment: OK seems like it's not supported. Only rectangles, ovals and round rectangles are supported. Thanks a lot! I can accept this as an answer if you want to post one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that a `View` can only be clipped to a rectangle, a rounded rectangle, or an oval `Outline`. Rather, a `View` can only be clipped to an `Outline` that is defined specifically with a `setRect()`, `setRoundRect()`, or `setOval()` method. An `Outline` set with a `Path` will not work, even though the `Path` itself may be one of the aforementioned shapes.

This is documented in several places, though not particularly well, in my opinion.

[`View#setClipToOutline()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClipToOutline(boolean)):

> Note that this flag will only be respected if the View's Outline returns true from [`canClip()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html#canClip()).

[`Outline#canClip()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html#canClip()):

> Currently, only Outlines that can be represented as a rectangle, circle, or round rect support clipping.

[Defining Shadows and Clipping Views - Clip Views](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Clip):

> Only rectangle, circle, and round rectangle outlines support clipping, as determined by the [`Outline.canClip()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html#canClip()) method.

At first look, this didn't seem consistent with `Outline`'s own inner workings, as a convex `Path` is, in fact, used internally for non-circular ovals. However, it does make sense to simply disallow all externally defined `Path`s, rather than expend the resources necessary to determine if an arbitrary `Path` is valid.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! IMHO it would be much clearer to throw an exception if someone tries to do clipping with an Outline when canClip() returns false.

Answer (score 22):

I know it is not helping in clipping but still, we can take the advantage of `outline.setConvexPath(path);` in elevation shadow since it's working fine as an outline for the elevation shadow around the path.

I attached an image to make it even more clear in which:

**First image**: ImageView with [Image with shadow]

```
android:outlineProvider="bounds"  
android:elevation="4dp"
```

**Second image**: CustomImageView with `canvas.clipPath(getShapePath())` in `onDraw()` method [we will get the clipped image but shadow still show as a rectangle bound]

```
android:outlineProvider="bounds"  
android:elevation="4dp"
```

**Third image**: CustomImageView with `canvas.clipPath(getShapePath())` in `onDraw()` method and `outline?.setConvexPath(getShapePath())` in `ViewOutlineProvider`. [we will get the clipped image and shadow will be aligned with the clipped image]

```
android:outlineProvider="bounds" // this will have no effect since it will be override by setConvexPath  
android:elevation="4dp"
```

[image: Valid XHTML]

[Download Source Code](https://github.com/GaurawNegi/outline-example-android)

Comment: it seems you wanted to upload some images in your answer but you didn't please edit your answer and upload them to clarify your content.

Comment: @Saeed yes, I want to upload the image but It required 10 reputation points since I am new I don't have any. as soon as I will get 10 reputation point I will update :-)

Comment: Could you share all the code for the third image example? Where is `getShapePath()` defined?

Comment: @DavidAlbers Sure, I would make it available to you probably within a week or two

Comment: @GaurawNegi Your third image with `outline?.setConvexPath(getShapePath())` won't work if path is not convex.

Comment: @JimitPatel native android shadow only works with a convex outline, if you think about the shapes like an oval, rounded rectangle or rectangle they all are the convex path, 
but if we want for non-convex path then we can use  :

paint.setShadowLayer(shadowPadding, 0f, 0f, shadowColor)

or you can check out this new drawable which will work for concave as well via drawing fake shadows:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable

Comment: Though it worked for Android 29 (ViewOutlineProvider works on 29), it is not working for different versions (tested on lollipop). It is said that shadow layer is meant for text rather than for paths

Comment: @DavidAlbers, as I promised, here is the [Complete Source Code](https://github.com/GaurawNegi/outline-example-android)

Comment: Luffy is a rubber man - he can bend in any shape